# Start a process with a SafeFileHandle

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Is there any way I can request permissions, or start the exe that is stored and have it delete on close after launching it? I'm trying to make the updater as clean as possible, in case for some reason the calling executable cannot start again, the updater will be cleaned up regardless.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
       string lpFileName,
       EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
       EFileShare dwShareMode,
       IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
       ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
       EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
       IntPtr hTemplateFile);


    public static void Main()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var updaterBytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://securechat.cz.cc/updater/download");

        var fileHandle = CreateFile("Updater.exe", EFileAccess.GenericRead | EFileAccess.GenericWrite, EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.CreateAlways, EFileAttributes.Hidden | EFileAttributes.DeleteOnClose, IntPtr.Zero);
        var fileStream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.Write);
        fileStream.Write(updaterBytes, 0, updaterBytes.Length);
        Process.Start("Updater.exe", "SecureChat Client");
    }

    [Flags]
    enum EFileAccess : uint
    {
        //
        // Standart Section
        //

        AccessSystemSecurity = 0x1000000,   // AccessSystemAcl access type
        MaximumAllowed = 0x2000000,     // MaximumAllowed access type

        Delete = 0x10000,
        ReadControl = 0x20000,
        WriteDAC = 0x40000,
        WriteOwner = 0x80000,
        Synchronize = 0x100000,

        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        StandardRightsRead = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsWrite = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsExecute = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsAll = 0x1F0000,
        SpecificRightsAll = 0xFFFF,

        FILE_READ_DATA = 0x0001,        // file & pipe
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001,       // directory
        FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x0002,       // file & pipe
        FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x0002,         // directory
        FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x0004,      // file
        FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x0004,     // directory
        FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE = 0x0004, // named pipe
        FILE_READ_EA = 0x0008,          // file & directory
        FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x0010,         // file & directory
        FILE_EXECUTE = 0x0020,          // file
        FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x0020,         // directory
        FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x0040,     // directory
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080,      // all
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100,     // all

        //
        // Generic Section
        //

        GenericRead = 0x80000000,
        GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
        GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
        GenericAll = 0x10000000,

        SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x00FFFF,
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS =
        StandardRightsRequired |
        Synchronize |
        0x1FF,

        FILE_GENERIC_READ =
        StandardRightsRead |
        FILE_READ_DATA |
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
        FILE_READ_EA |
        Synchronize,

        FILE_GENERIC_WRITE =
        StandardRightsWrite |
        FILE_WRITE_DATA |
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES |
        FILE_WRITE_EA |
        FILE_APPEND_DATA |
        Synchronize,

        FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE =
        StandardRightsExecute |
          FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
          FILE_EXECUTE |
          Synchronize
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum EFileShare : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        None = 0x00000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request read access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request read access. 
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for read access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Read = 0x00000001,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request write access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request write access. 
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for write access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Write = 0x00000002,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request delete access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request delete access.
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for delete access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Delete = 0x00000004
    }

    public enum ECreationDisposition : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new file. The function fails if a specified file exists.
        /// </summary>
        New = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new file, always. 
        /// If a file exists, the function overwrites the file, clears the existing attributes, combines the specified file attributes, 
        /// and flags with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, but does not set the security descriptor that the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure specifies.
        /// </summary>
        CreateAlways = 2,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file. The function fails if the file does not exist. 
        /// </summary>
        OpenExisting = 3,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file, always. 
        /// If a file does not exist, the function creates a file as if dwCreationDisposition is CREATE_NEW.
        /// </summary>
        OpenAlways = 4,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file and truncates it so that its size is 0 (zero) bytes. The function fails if the file does not exist.
        /// The calling process must open the file with the GENERIC_WRITE access right. 
        /// </summary>
        TruncateExisting = 5
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum EFileAttributes : uint
    {
        Readonly = 0x00000001,
        Hidden = 0x00000002,
        System = 0x00000004,
        Directory = 0x00000010,
        Archive = 0x00000020,
        Device = 0x00000040,
        Normal = 0x00000080,
        Temporary = 0x00000100,
        SparseFile = 0x00000200,
        ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
        Compressed = 0x00000800,
        Offline = 0x00001000,
        NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
        Encrypted = 0x00004000,
        Write_Through = 0x80000000,
        Overlapped = 0x40000000,
        NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
        RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
        SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
        DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
        BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
        PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
        OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
        OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
        FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `CreateFile` clearly states that `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` requires `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, a requirement that you code does not heed.

However, even if you do heed that requirement, your code will still fail. That's because when creating a process the loader requests exclusive access to the file. Which is not compatible with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

You will have to give up on this endeavour. Save the file to disk in a temporary location. Execute the update process. Wait for it to complete. Delete the file. No p/invoke necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately I thought this would be the case.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way would be to have your current program wait for Updater.exe to finish, then delete it:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "Updater.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
System.IO.File.Delete("Updater.exe");
```